# Find and replace text in audio ppt using macros from excel

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

i have a project to find and replace words in powerpoint from excel and then save the powerpoint. My code is working fine. But when ppt has mp3 then it giving errors. Please see the code and tell me what change i should do.

```
          Sub pptopen()

    Dim a  As Integer
    For a = 2 To 4

   Dim pptApp As PowerPoint.Application
   Dim pptPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
   Dim pptSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
   Dim i As Integer, strString As String
       Set pptApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
       Set pptPres = pptApp.Presentations.Add(msoTrue) ' create a new presentation

       Set pptPres = pptApp.Presentations.Open("D:\BirminghamAL.pptx")
       Dim oSld As Slide
       Dim oTxtRng As TextRange
       Dim oTmpRng As TextRange
       Dim strWhatReplace As String, strReplaceText As String

        ' write find text
       strWhatReplace = "Birmingham"
        ' write change text
       strReplaceText = Cells(a, 1).Value

        ' go during each slides
       For Each oSld In pptPres.Slides
            ' go during each shapes and textRanges
           For Each oshp In oSld.Shapes
           If oshp.Type = 14 Or oshp.Type = 17 Then
                ' replace in TextFrame
               Set oTxtRng = oshp.TextFrame.TextRange
               Set oTmpRng = oTxtRng.Replace( _
               FindWhat:=strWhatReplace, _
               Replacewhat:=strReplaceText, _
               WholeWords:=True)
               End If


               Do While Not oTmpRng Is Nothing

                   Set oTxtRng = oTxtRng.Characters _
                   (oTmpRng.Start + oTmpRng.Length, oTxtRng.Length)
                   Set oTmpRng = oTxtRng.Replace( _
                   FindWhat:=strWhatReplace, _
                   Replacewhat:=strReplaceText, _
                   WholeWords:=True)

               Loop
           Next oshp
       Next oSld
       Dim strWhatReplace1 As String, strReplaceText1 As String

        ' write find text
       strWhatReplace1 = "AL"
        ' write change text
       strReplaceText1 = Cells(a, 2).Value

        ' go during each slides
       For Each oSld In pptPres.Slides
            ' go during each shapes and textRanges
           For Each oshp In oSld.Shapes
                 If oshp.Type = 14 Or oshp.Type = 17 Then
                ' replace in TextFrame
               Set oTxtRng = oshp.TextFrame.TextRange
               Set oTmpRng = oTxtRng.Replace( _
               FindWhat:=strWhatReplace1, _
               Replacewhat:=strReplaceText1, _
               WholeWords:=True)
                 End If
               Do While Not oTmpRng Is Nothing

                   Set oTxtRng = oTxtRng.Characters _
                   (oTmpRng.Start + oTmpRng.Length, oTxtRng.Length)
                   Set oTmpRng = oTxtRng.Replace( _
                   FindWhat:=strWhatReplace1, _
                   Replacewhat:=strReplaceText1, _
                   WholeWords:=True)

               Loop
           Next oshp
       Next oSld

      pptPres.SaveAs ("D:\change\" & strReplaceText & "." & strReplaceText1 & ".pptx")

       Next a

   End Sub
```

Comment: If there is a powerpoint which has no mp3 then it work fine. As soon as i call audio mp3 then it is giving function errors

Comment: `For Each oShp In oSld.Shapes` You have to ensure after this line and before this line `Set oTxtRng = oShp.TextFrame.TextRange` that the shape is a Textbox

Answer (score 0):

Here is an explanation to my above comment (right below your question).

My slide looks like this

[image]

If you notice that not all shapes have the `.TextFrame` property. So all you have to do is find out which shapes you want to handle.

Here is a very basic code to check what all shapes you have on your slide(s)

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim shp As Shape

    For Each shp In ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes
        Debug.Print shp.Name; "--"; shp.Type
    Next
End Sub
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

So you can try something like this.

**Note**: 14 is just an example. You need to decide what kind of shape do you want to address.

```
For Each oSld In pptPres.Slides
    For Each oshp In oSld.Shapes
        If oshp.Type = 14 Then
            '~~> Rest of your code
        End If
    Next oshp
Next oSld
```

**FOLLOWUP**

I just tried this code and it works.

```
Option Explicit

Sub pptopen()
    Dim pptApp As New PowerPoint.Application
    Dim pptPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim pptSlide As PowerPoint.Slide, oSld As PowerPoint.Slide
    Dim oshp As PowerPoint.Shape

    Dim oTxtRng As TextRange, oTmpRng As TextRange
    Dim oTxtRng1 As TextRange, oTmpRng1 As TextRange

    Dim strString As String, strWhatReplace As String, strReplaceText As String
    Dim strWhatReplace1 As String, strReplaceText1 As String

    Dim a As Integer, i As Integer

    Set pptPres = pptApp.Presentations.Open("D:\BirminghamAL.pptx")

    For a = 2 To 4
        ' write find text
        strWhatReplace = "Birmingham"
        ' write change text
        strReplaceText = Cells(a, 1).Value
        ' write find text
        strWhatReplace1 = "AL"
        ' write change text
        strReplaceText1 = Cells(a, 2).Value

        ' go during each slides
        For Each oSld In pptPres.Slides
            ' go during each shapes and textRanges
            For Each oshp In oSld.Shapes
                If oshp.Type = 14 Or oshp.Type = 17 Then
                    ' replace in TextFrame
                    Set oTxtRng = oshp.TextFrame.TextRange
                    Set oTmpRng = oTxtRng.Replace(FindWhat:=strWhatReplace, _
                                  Replacewhat:=strReplaceText, WholeWords:=True)

                    Do While Not oTmpRng Is Nothing
                       Set oTxtRng = oTxtRng.Characters(oTmpRng.Start + oTmpRng.Length, oTxtRng.Length)
                       Set oTmpRng = oTxtRng.Replace(FindWhat:=strWhatReplace, Replacewhat:=strReplaceText, WholeWords:=True)
                    Loop

                    ' replace in TextFrame
                    Set oTxtRng1 = oshp.TextFrame.TextRange
                    Set oTmpRng1 = oTxtRng1.Replace(FindWhat:=strWhatReplace1, _
                                  Replacewhat:=strReplaceText1, WholeWords:=True)

                    Do While Not oTmpRng1 Is Nothing
                       Set oTxtRng1 = oTxtRng1.Characters(oTmpRng1.Start + oTmpRng1.Length, oTxtRng1.Length)
                       Set oTmpRng1 = oTxtRng1.Replace(FindWhat:=strWhatReplace1, Replacewhat:=strReplaceText1, WholeWords:=True)
                    Loop

                End If
            Next oshp
        Next oSld

        pptPres.SaveAs Filename:="D:\change\" & strReplaceText & "_" & strReplaceText1 & ".pptx", FileFormat:=ppSaveAsDefault
    Next a
End Sub
```

Comment: Siddarth sir it is not yet running. Throwing errors in the line u gave

Comment: can u give me your email id so that i can send you whole file

Comment: ppt file here

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_D1XwD_du3jUHpWY0dOa18wVlU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The files are here
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_D1XwD_du3jMnNIellqLVhadTg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Which line in my code is giving you the error? I am downloading the file in the meantime

Comment: Set oTxtRng = oShp.TextFrame.TextRange

Comment: But I never gave you that code... Did you read my post above carefully?

Comment: i have given u before executing one. Read the macro procedure to start. in that there is normal ppt and it is working. I gave u audio ppt also. Using audio ppt it is giving error.

Comment: yeah i read ur post. u asked me to add a line before and after it. I did so but no effect came

Comment: That is because you have 2 shape types `14` and `17`. So change your code to `If oshp.Type = 14 or oshp.Type = 17 Then` BTW I didn't see any shape which has a media file?

Comment: sir i did this also but is giving error. You also do once. You will find the error

Comment: first from ur code i found out the shape then implemented it.

Comment: I just tested this code form powerpoint and it works with no problem... http://wikisend.com/download/417482/untitled.png

Comment: can you give me the code in notepad file so that i can implement over there. As i am implementing and i could not get it.This is my project and i am too worried. Please send me at fattah@gmail.com

Comment: I have attached a screenshot with the entire code. You can type it seeing it from there...

Comment: but when i merge with my existing code then it is not working

Comment: yeah. I tried in Excel too. it is giving error where we save the file. Now what is happening the replacement is done as 1,2 and it is not saving

Comment: Can you edit and update your question above with the exact code that you are using from Excel.

Comment: pptPres.SaveAs ("D:\change\" & strReplaceText & "." & strReplaceText1 & ".pptx")    in this line it giving error. and when a poerpoint comes then repplace test are as 1, 2. not as before

Comment: Why are you replacing `"Birmingham"` with `"Birmingham"` What I mean is if `a = 2` then `strReplaceText = Cells(a, 1).Value` becomes `"Birmingham"`

Comment: Also your saveas statement should be like this `pptPres.SaveAs FileName:="D:\change\" & strReplaceText & "." & strReplaceText1 & ".pptx", FileFormat:=ppSaveAsDefault`

Comment: I have to replace in first ppt only.means i have 5000 city name and state name. These ppt has to send to those people. From excel sheet it is fetching city name and replacing with Birmingham and State to

Comment: so basically your entire code is working accept the saveas part right?

Comment: see my excel sheet and data over there. I have to replace those city name with Brimgham and state name too then save in the format [city][state] form

Comment: the oroginal ppt i send u was working fine. But when i use the If condition then replace it not happening fine. in the city name 1 is coming and state 2 is coming

Comment: that result i need in new ppt with audio one

Comment: Why do you want me to mail it to you if I have already updated the code in the post above?. Refresh the page

Comment: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_D1XwD_du3jbHJKbjRJT2VjUUE/edit?usp=sharing

see the error i am getting

Comment: You have to add reference to MS powerpoint. Go to tools menu in VBA and click on references and then select MS Powerpoint Object xx.xx library

Comment: Sorry my crystal ball is not working. So you will have to tell me which line you are getting the error :)

Comment: Set oTmpRng = oTxtRng.Replace(FindWhat:=strWhatReplace, _
compile error :method or data member not found

Comment: i am doing this coding in excel

Comment: yeah i add the reference. Before it was not getting into pptopen also. Now it is going after adding refrences

Comment: Insert a new module in the excel file and then paste the code as I have posted above. Add the reference and run it again. I just re-tested it and it works just fine.

Comment: Can you tell me one thing how to convert 5 into five and 100000 in 1 lakh. Does stack flow has this code. It yes then by whichname